# Composite not working in blender

Tags: compositing-nodes

i do render of my scene in 2 different render layers but i am unable to composite in a single image please help me. thanks

[image]

Comment: Looks like you need to enable your main layer as a mask layer for your cloth. Should be in your render layer settings.

Answer (score 1):

Set your main layer(s) as a mask layer.

[image]

This makes it so that when something covers up the layer in space, it becomes transparent in the renderlayer.

Comment: i tried it but it is not working for me

Comment: please help me. i didn't get my answer yet. pls give me a link for this tutorial. thanx

Answer (score 0):

You may try the Z Combine node to combine layers instead of Alpha Over:
[image: z combine node]